# FreeBSD on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: freebsd, raspberry-pi, u-boot, bootable

I want to build **FreeBSD custom Image** for my **Raspberry Pi2**. I have read about the boot process in RPi2. I also went through the  [chrochet build instruction](https://github.com/freebsd/crochet/wiki/How-to-Build-a-Disk-Image) document.
I learned from some websites that the firmware is not up-todate. So BSD cannot be booted on RPi2 . 
Please provide pointers to  build custom image of FREEBSD for RPi2

Comment: The code simply hasn't been written yet. Both uboot and the kernel are going to have to be modified. Watch this thread for updates: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/raspberry-pi-2.50291/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to contribute to this development and can programme in  C++. How can i get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest release 11 of FreeBSD added support for BCM2836 making it compatible for Pi2.
https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi